# Post Image instead of image link on Laravel server

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have two data fields in my Flutter app, one for CategoryName and Another for Category Image and I can successfully POST data to the server with TextFormFields, but I want to upload the image to the server instead of pasting the image link from textformfield.

My TextFormFields views

```
Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: categoryIcon,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Category Icon'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: categoryName,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Category Name'),
          ),
          !isLoading
              ? RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  onPressed: () {
                    var category = Category();
                    category.name = categoryName.text;
                    category.icon = categoryIcon.text;
                    _postCategory(context, category);
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Post Comment",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator()
        ],
      )
```

Please help me to send an image to the laravel server.

```
_postCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) async {
    var _categoryService = CategoryService();
    var postCategory = await _categoryService.postCategory(category);
    var response = json.decode(postCategory.body);
    if (response['result'] == true) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CategoryList()));
    }
  }
```

Laravel Server code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        $category->name =  $request->input('categoryName');
        $category->icon = $request->input('categoryIcon');

        if($category->save()){
           return response(['result' => true, 'name' => $category ->name]);
        }
       return redirect()->back()->with('failed', 'Could not saved');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

   $request->validate([
            'categoryIcon' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
       $imageName = time().'.'.$request->categoryIcon->extension();  
        $request->categoryIcon->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        /* Store $imageName name in DATABASE from HERE */
        $category = new Category();
        $category->name =  $request->input('categoryName');
        $category->icon = $imageName ;

        if($category->save()){
           return response(['result' => true, 'name' => $category ->name]);
        }
       return redirect()->back()->with('failed', 'Could not saved');
    }
```

Comment: Please provide me help for dart file